# variable hard coded vs. from file

Tags: powershell

I'm still a beginner in PowerShell and I'm trying the first things. I know a lot more about VBA.
I am currently writing a small tool which should read several IP's from an .ini file and ping them. The result should then be displayed in a DataGridView. For testing I have entered the IP's directly into the code `$IP= '10.10.10.1', '10.10.10.2', '10.10.10.3'` These IP's will then be tested via ForEach:

```
$IP | ForEach-Object { 
$result = TestConnection $_ -count 1 -Quiet
$DataGridView.RowsAdd($_, $result) 
}
```

Works as it should. However, when I read the IP's from the .ini file it does not work. The IP's are not separated in the loop. If I use a write-host $IP, the following is displayed for both types (.ini and hard coded): `10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.3`

Parsing the .ini file:

```
Get-Content config.ini | ForEach-Object -Begin {$config=@{}} -Process {$store =[regex]::split($_,'=') if(($store[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($store[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True) -and ($store[0].StartsWith("#") -ne $True)) {$configs.Add($store[0], $store[1})}}

$IP = $configs.Get_Item("IP")

config.ini:
IP=10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an ini file, put all the IP addresses on separate lines in a simple text file:

```
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.3
```

Then read it into your variable with `Get-Content`:

```
$IP = Get-Content path\to\file\with\IPs.txt
```

`Get-Content` will return an array with each line of text as a separate element, given you the exact same result as if you'd done `'10.10.10.1', '10.10.10.2', '10.10.10.3'` in the source code

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I'm using an .ini file to exclude some setup setup information in there. The idea was to use the same file for the IP's. now I have to deal with two files.

Comment: @pf2pfo2 If you update [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72965666/edit) with 1) a sample ini file and 2) the code you're currently using to parse the ini file, I might be able to suggest improvements based on that :)